# How to show $M_p$ is a field, where $M$ represents $2 \times 2$ matrices of a certain type, and p is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, field-theory

So I'm doing this question, and I'm kinda very stuck. I do NOT want an entire answer, but I am asking for some clarification regarding what to do, or how to approach the problem. Even just comments would suffice, if they can help clarify what to do.

Okay, so I'm given $M_p$ as representing all $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form
$\begin {bmatrix} n & m \\ -m & n\end {bmatrix} $, where $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, and $p$ is prime.

I need to show $M_p$ is a field for a given $p$.

My main confusion is, how can I rewrite $m$ and $n$ in a way that I can work with them? For a ring to be a field, it would need to be commutative, have an identity, and have a multiplicative inverse for all elements, right?

In this case, matrix multiplication is commutative, and the identity matrix would still hold as well. But I do need to show that there does exist a multiplicative inverse. And that would mean that the determinant should be non-zero for whatever $m,n$ I take s.t the matrix is non-zero. So say I take the determinant, and set $m^2+n^2 \neq \bar{0}$ (mod p). Can I just say that $m^2+n^2 = a + pb$, where a and b are any two random integers such that a is not divisible by p? If I do this, I feel like I can't really get anything ahead, as I just get an expression that I don't really know what to do with.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? I'm not very skilled with abstract algebra at all, and I haven't touched proofs in a very long time, so I feel like I'm not thinking about this question the way that I should.

Could someone please help? Any sort of hint would be amazingly helpful, I just need to know what direction I should go in :/

Comment: Have you tried for small values of p? That might give you some ideas about the structure of $M_{p}$

Comment: @Liddo I'm not exactly sure what to do... I don't need to show this for all p's, since apparently it should be a field for p=7, but not for p=13? But I can't really figure out how to continue what I'm doing for a specific value of p, or if I'm working on this correctly at all, to be honest.

Comment: You need to assume $p$ is remainder 3 when divided by 4. $p$ can't be written as a sum of two squares or some matrices can't be reversed.

Comment: At least for $p=2$ the statement does not hold, pick the matrix with all $1$s, this is not invertible.

Comment: This might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942678/how-to-solve-x2y2-pz2-in-x-y-z-in-mathbbn-if-p-is-such-a-prime-that

Comment: when  $m, n\in \mathbb R$ you can use matrices $\begin {bmatrix} n & m \\ -m & n\end {bmatrix}$ to get the field $\mathbb C$.  Why? because the multiplicative group $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ doesn't have an order 4 element. Same idea here: with $m, n \in \mathbb F_p$ then a non-zero matrix with determinant of zero $\implies (n^{-1}m)^2=-1$ so check the multiplicative group $\mathbb F_p-\{0\}$ for an order 4 element.  (Special care is needed for characteristic 2 as is common.)

Comment: @Liddo YES THANK YOU, this helped a LOT!! I've checked for p=5, 7, and 13, and have understood how to show this. Thank you!

Comment: @user8675309 okay so this is actually really interesting, I didn't know to check it like this. BUT I think this is super good to know, so thank you!